Is there an R function for colouring the points of two clusters/groups on an MDS plot?
I am trying to plot the following:
mydistdata <- metaMDS(mydata, autotransform = FALSE)
mydistdata$stress
plot(mydistdata, type='t')

This produces a plot that has the points (as text) recorded all in black and white.
Now, I can't fathom how to colour in the clustered points differently to the less clustered points. Ideally, I would like 17, 44, 24b, 35, 31b, 43, 26, 30a, 40 and 34 to be different colour to the other points on the plot.
The error species scores not available is also popping up but I don't want the species scores to be on the plot anyway, just the sites.

if you have a variable (or a column of a data.frame) which lists each group for each point you can use the option col in the function plot().
best
nic
